# How do I downgrade puppetdbquery?

Tags: puppet, package-management, puppetmaster, puppetdb

I'm getting an error on puppet runs which use puppetdb queries:

```
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Loading facts
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: undefined method `server_urls' for #<Puppet::Util::Puppetdb::Config:0x00000003cd66c8> at /etc/puppet/local-modules/monitoring/manifests/init.pp:14 on node hostname.goes.here
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

By running the puppetmaster with `--verbose`, I get [a warning](https://github.com/dalen/puppet-puppetdbquery/blob/master/lib/puppetdb/connection.rb#L22) which looks helpful:

```
Warning: It looks like you are using a PuppetDB version < 3.0.
This version of puppetdbquery requires at least PuppetDB 3.0 to work.
Downgrade to puppetdbquery 1.x to use it with PuppetDB 2.x.
```

PuppetDB 3.0 isn't available on the machine in question, so I'm looking at downgrading `puppetdbquery`.  However, I can't find where/how this is installed.  So far I've checked `dpkg` (I'm running Debian Jessie), `gem` and `librarian-puppet`, but none of them appear to have installed `puppetdbquery`.
Is there anyway to find where it came from and how to downgrade it?

Comment: Have you tried `puppet module list`?

Comment: Yes, that's being managed by librarian-puppet, so it's not in there either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To track down the file (thanks to [ssm's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/748499/137962) for the link the source), I did:

```
find / -name connection.rb
```

Then I grepped the results for those which included "It looks like you are using a PuppetDB version < 3.0.", I ended up with one file:

```
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/ruby-puppetdb-2.1.1/lib/puppetdb/connection.rb
```

At first this confused me, because it makes no mention of puppetdbquery, but on closer inspection of [the repository](https://github.com/dalen/puppet-puppetdbquery/blob/master/ruby-puppetdb.gemspec), I saw that the gemspec it includes calls itself "ruby-puppetdb", not puppetdbquery.
Therefore, the fix was to run:

```
gem uninstall ruby-puppetdb --version 2.1.1
```

I had older versions of the gem installed, so the system fell back to using those instead.

To summarise:
**When installed as a gem, puppetdbquery is called ruby-puppetdb**

Answer (score 2):

[puppetdbquery](https://github.com/dalen/puppet-puppetdbquery) is a puppet module, and even though it may not be in your Puppetfile, it may be installed as a dependency of one of your other modules.

Take a look in the directories listed in the modulepath on your puppet master.

The error message you quote is found in [lib/puppetdb/connection.rb](https://github.com/dalen/puppet-puppetdbquery/blob/29fb56540a6cff732c69f697e6e9d33ef656430c/lib/puppetdb/connection.rb#L22) in that module.

Comment: I checked the directories in the modulepath and there was no sign of puppetdbquery.  However, your link to connection.rb was very helpful and it prompted me to do a `find` for that file name and then grep the results for the error message.  Thanks for the hint!